# How to post document date and document number in general journal

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

i'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to programatically set the document number and date in the general journal trans, under the tab invoice. I'm trying to post to the general journal in ax 2012 with x++. I currently have this code that works but there is no method under the ledgerjournal trans to set the document no or date. infact alot of the setters are missing and only has linenum account type, journal num etc etc.
How can i set these fields? below i have some code

```
static void TestLedgerJournalImport(Args _args)
{
// Set these variables.
LedgerJournalNameId                     journalName = 'GenJrn';
SelectableDataArea                      company = '019';
TransDate                               transactionDate = 30\6\2012;

str                                     line1MainAccount = '131310';
str                                     line1FullAccount = '131310--';

str                                     line2MainAccount = '131310';
str                                     line2FullAccount = '131310-10-';
str                                     line2Dimension1Name = 'Department';
str                                     line2Dimension1Value = 'ACCT';

LedgerGeneralJournalService             ledgerGeneralJournalService;
LedgerGeneralJournal                    ledgerGeneralJournal;

AfStronglyTypedDataContainerList        journalHeaderCollection;
LedgerGeneralJournal_LedgerJournalTable journalHeader;
AifEntityKeyList                        journalHeaderCollectionKeyList;
RecId                                   journalHeaderRecId;

AfStronglyTypedDataContainerList        journalLineCollection;
LedgerGeneralJournal_LedgerJournalTrans journalLine1;
AifMultiTypeAccount                     journalLine1LedgerDimension;
LedgerGeneralJournal_LedgerJournalTrans journalLine2;
AifMultiTypeAccount                     journalLine2LedgerDimension;
AifDimensionAttributeValue              journalLine2Dim1;
AfStronglyTypedDataContainerList        journalLine2DimensionCollection;
;

ledgerGeneralJournalService = LedgerGeneralJournalService::construct();
ledgerGeneralJournal = new LedgerGeneralJournal();

// Create journal header.
journalHeaderCollection = ledgerGeneralJournal.createLedgerJournalTable();
journalHeader = journalHeaderCollection.insertNew(1);
journalHeader.parmJournalName(journalName);

// Create journal lines.
journalLineCollection = journalHeader.createLedgerJournalTrans();

// Line 1
journalLine1 = journalLineCollection.insertNew(1);
journalLine1.parmLineNum(1.00);
journalLine1.parmCompany(company);
journalLine1.parmTransDate(transactionDate);
journalLine1.parmAccountType(LedgerJournalACType::Ledger);
journalLine1.parmTxt('Test journal transaction');
journalLine1.parmAmountCurDebit(100.00);
journalLine1LedgerDimension = journalLine1.createLedgerDimension();
journalLine1LedgerDimension.parmAccount(line1MainAccount);
journalLine1LedgerDimension.parmDisplayValue(line1FullAccount);
journalLine1.parmLedgerDimension(journalLine1LedgerDimension);

// Line 2
journalLine2 = journalLineCollection.insertNew(2);
journalLine2.parmLineNum(2.00);
journalLine2.parmCompany(company);
journalLine2.parmTransDate(transactionDate);
journalLine2.parmAccountType(LedgerJournalACType::Ledger);
journalLine2.parmTxt('Test journal transaction');
journalLine2.parmAmountCurCredit(100.00);
journalLine2LedgerDimension = journalLine2.createLedgerDimension();
journalLine2DimensionCollection = journalLine2LedgerDimension.createValues();
journalLine2Dim1 = new AifDimensionAttributeValue();
journalLine2Dim1.parmName(line2Dimension1Name);
journalLine2Dim1.parmValue(line2Dimension1Value);
journalLine2DimensionCollection.add(journalLine2Dim1);
journalLine2LedgerDimension.parmAccount(line2MainAccount);
journalLine2LedgerDimension.parmDisplayValue(line2FullAccount);
journalLine2LedgerDimension.parmValues(journalLine2DimensionCollection);
journalLine2.parmLedgerDimension(journalLine2LedgerDimension);

// Insert records.
journalHeader.parmLedgerJournalTrans(journalLineCollection);
ledgerGeneralJournal.parmLedgerJournalTable(journalHeaderCollection);
journalHeaderCollectionKeyList =
    LedgerGeneralJournalService.create(ledgerGeneralJournal);
journalHeaderRecId =
    journalHeaderCollectionKeyList.getEntityKey(1).parmRecId();

info(strFmt("LedgerJournalTable.Recid = %1", int642str(journalHeaderRecId)));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it like that, you're making more work for yourself.  I just wrote this example for you.  I hacked up a more complex piece of code I wrote, so the offsetDefaultDimension I just left in for some example code.

```
static void Job3(Args _args)
{
    AxLedgerJournalTable                journalTable = AxLedgerJournalTable::construct();
    LedgerJournalTable                  ledgerJournalTable;
    LedgerJournalName                   ledgerJournalName = LedgerJournalName::find('GenJrn');
    AxLedgerJournalTrans                journalTrans = AxLedgerJournalTrans::construct();
    DimensionAttribute                  dimensionAttribute;
    DimensionAttributeValue             dimensionAttributeValue;
    DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage   dimStorage;
    LedgerDimensionAccount              ledgerDimension = DimensionDefaultingService::serviceCreateLedgerDimension(DimensionStorage::getDefaultAccountForMainAccountNum('131310'));

    journalTable.parmJournalName(ledgerJournalName.JournalName);
    journalTable.parmJournalType(ledgerJournalName.JournalType);
    journalTable.save();

    ttsBegin;
    ledgerJournalTable = LedgerJournalTable::findByRecId(journalTable.ledgerJournalTable().RecId, true);

    // The name gets reset if no journal number is provided, so we can just update afterwords
    ledgerJournalTable.Name = 'My Custom Journal Name/Description';
    ledgerJournalTable.update();
    ttsCommit;

    journalTrans.parmJournalNum(journalTable.ledgerJournalTable().JournalNum);
    journalTrans.parmTransDate(today());
    journalTrans.parmCurrencyCode('USD');
    journalTrans.parmTxt('AlexOnDAX.blogspot.com');
    journalTrans.parmDocumentNum('MyDocNumber');
    journalTrans.parmDocumentDate(today() - 1);

    journalTrans.parmAccountType(LedgerJournalACType::Ledger);
    journalTrans.parmLedgerDimension(DimensionAttributeValueCombination::find(ledgerDimension).RecId);

    journalTrans.parmAmountCurDebit(100.00);
    journalTrans.save();

    info("Done");
}
```

Comment: I tried to run this and i got this error. Function DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage.addItemValues has been incorrectly called.  Also i just want the piece of code on how to set the document no and document name.

Comment: What field are you referring to when you say "document name"? And the error your received is because my main account and Business Unit are probably different.  You just need minor tweaks to my code to make it work for you environment.

Comment: I just edited it, copy/paste the job now and I think it will work in your environment.

Comment: When you post to the general journal and you click on "lines" theres overview, general, invoice tabs etc. when you click on invoice tab how do you populate document: and document date:

Comment: oh i just noticed you are using the axledgerjournaltrans and i was just useing ledgerjournaltrans

Comment: You said "document name" and you meant "document date" and I got you 99.9% of the way there, you can figure out to add this line `journalTrans.parmDocumentDate(today() - 1);`

Comment: thanks so far, actually i get this error now Failed to create a session; confirm that the user has the proper privileges to log on to Microsoft Dynamics.

Comment: At this point, I've more than answered your question. You are going to have to do some programming yourself as that's part of the fun! That issue seems to be environment related. http://www.ksaelen.be/wordpresses/dynamicsaxblog/2013/02/ax2012-r2-db-sync-failed-to-create-a-session/

Comment: your right i fixed it anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: one more questions.. is there a parameter to set the department name?

Comment: This code should be very straight forward...check if .parmWhatever exists. You need to find out the name of the actual field you want to set.

Comment: actually they are dimensions for department and location etc etc.. it happens in this line. i would like to set know how to set the other dimensions.  LedgerDimensionAccount              ledgerDimension = DimensionDefaultingService::serviceCreateLedgerDimension(DimensionStorage::getDefaultAccountForMainAccountNum('701300')

Comment: I had specifically left that code in as a "sample" for you, but you asked me to remove it.  You said "Also i just want the piece of code on how to set the document no and document name". Click on the post where it says `edited Jan 9 at 20:36` and you can see the edit history, and you will see the code to do that type of stuff.  Is your primary role a developer?

Comment: And yes i remember you had that part in. I just wanted to get it working to post to the general journal and you have helped me alot to acommplish that.  Now that i want to go back and add the dimensions. i added that code in and i'm back to the error i get for. dimStorage = DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage::find(0);  Function DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage.addItemValues has been incorrectly called. again i'm learning x++ and how to do this for the first time

Comment: i'm trying to replace it with the proper recid

Comment: This needs to be a new question. You should be able to google this, I can't program it for you or you won't learn.